# Firebase taking time to host files

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have been trying to host my website using firebase. I have a folder in which there is an index.html page and another html page which i have connected to the index through a button link. This "another html" page contains a large image. Apparently, when i upload these files two things take place really slow:

- The firebase takes time to host the site(around 9-10 min)
- The image inside the "another html" page takes an era to load on my desktop 
  but is fast in my mobile device.

What should i do to speed things up? For reference i have some images. If you need any more reference please do mention.

[image: firebase hosting]
[image: file structure inside my folder]

P.S The other html is index1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time it takes to deploy your site to Firebase Hosting is dependent on:

- the size of the site assets you're trying to deploy
- the bandwidth that you have available

And to a lesser degree:

- the time it takes your local machine to compress the site assets

In my extended usage, deploys typically take seconds, not minutes. But my sites are usually quite small and I tend to deploy when I'm on a connection with good bandwidth.

To make deploys faster, you'll either have to reduce the total size of what you're trying to deploy, or deploy when you're on a faster connection.